# how to dial a number and a code in winphone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In a windows phone app, how can I dial a number and then a code after the phone answers similar to the Nokia Conference app? It seems to be using something different than the PhoneCallTask which does not allow you to do anything special. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can assure you that this is NOT possible in WP7 or WP8 for average mortal developers.

Apps like Nokia Conference app get special (OEM) access to libraries that us muggles don't get.

For example the phone call intercept library and SMS intercept libraries.

Perhaps, just perhaps, in WP 8.1 you will be able to create a phone dialer app and be able to allow the user to assign your app as the default phone dialer. Then maybe you can do what you're asking. Currently in the WP7 and WP8 worlds though, this is black magic.

[MSDN Question: Windows phone programmatically intercepting incoming phone calls through app](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/17c6b467-ec66-4cf3-8772-54e77307ef68/windows-phone-programmatically-intercepting-incoming-phone-calls-through-app?forum=wpdevelop)

[Reference MSDN - Certification Requirements - Phone Functionality Section 5.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> 5.3.1 - Phone calls: The app must not delay or prevent the user from initiating a phone call, answering an incoming phone call, or ending a phone call.

You can apparently do this with a VIOP call